# Pass class as argument to check local variable

Tags: scala, class

I'm currently writing a parser in Scala and am trying to create an `eat` function that checks whether the next `Token` is of a certain case class and if so, consumes it. My current try is as follows and works correctly:

```
def eat[T](tokenType: TypeTag[T]) = currentToken match {
  case Plus() => if (tokenType == typeTag[Plus]) currentToken = lexer.getNextToken() else throw new Exception(tokenType.toString ++ " expected, " ++ currentToken.toString)
  case Minus() => if (tokenType == typeTag[Minus]) currentToken = lexer.getNextToken() else throw new Exception(tokenType.toString ++ " expected, " ++ currentToken.toString)
}
```

`Token`s are defined as follows:

```
trait Token
case class Plus() extends Token
case class Minus() extends Token
case class IntConst(n: Int) extends Token
case class FloatConst(x: Float) extends Token
```

Previously I did it with strings to specify the types, but passing a `TypeTag` already removes the possibility to try to eat a non existing type.

However, **tldr,** what I am trying to achieve is to be able to pass a type or class as argument and to check whether the currentToken is of that class.

I did find out how to pass a class as an argument with `def something(c: class[_])`, but then I would only know how to compare this to a given type, say `Int`. However, I want to compare it to the type of my currentToken. Can anybody point me in the right direction for achieving that?

Thanks.

### What I am hoping to achieve, (extended version)

At the current moment, I have working code, that does what is expected in (I think) a relatively efficient way. However, for every `Token` case class added, a new line to this function would have to be added as well, even though the main question answered by the `eat` function does not change. In an ideal world, I would hope to write something like the following pseudocode:

```
def eat(tokenClass: Class) = {
    if (classOf(currentToken) == tokenClass) getNextToken else throw exception
}
```

Which would never have to get extended. (Even better by the way would be if the parameter would only be allowed to be a case class of the trait Token).

Comment: Is this a simplified example, or do your tokens really have no fields? If that's the case, can't you check on value equality, instead of type equality?

Comment: @CyrilleCorpet Even if the tokens have fields, he can pattern match. Is there a particular reason why you need type tags here?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov you cannot pattern match on the abstract type `T`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestions. @CyrilleCorpet, this is a smaller example (I have more tokens than this), but not simplified as in: these are the actual tokens, so they do not have fields. My full program btw so far is on [GitHub](https://github.com/FlorianGit/Interpreter), but still changes quite often.

Comment: @CyrilleCorpet Why does he need `T`? He needs a `Token`.

Comment: I extended my question with a a clearer explanation of what I try to achieve and why I think that would be an improvement to the existing code (which works correctly).

Comment: @FlorianK it's still unclear if you can't compare on the value level instead of class level. If your `Token` trait is basically an enum, there is no need to bother with types.

Comment: @CyrilleCorpet I added two more examples of case classes, that make the example more representative. There are case classes with parameters, but none of the case classes implement functions (and they will never need that). I think it means that it is not basically an enum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since what you want to compare is actually runtime classes (and not compile time types), you can do something like this:

```
def eat[T](implicit T: ClassTag[T]) =
  if (T.runtimeClass == currentToken.getClass) getNextToken else throw exception
```

However, this will cause problems if your classes have type parameters (because of type erasure).

Comment: Great! This solved it out of the box! Given that it apparently took a while to understand my actual question, do you have suggestions of key phrases I could add to my quesion to make it more clearly understandable for the future?

Comment: No, the question was well defined (I had this answer for some time), I just wasn't sure you couldn't do something to avoid using reflection.